# C# classes in separate files?

Tags: c#

Should each class in my C# project get its own file (in your opinion)?

Comment: I write pretty clean code, but this is something I never gave much thought to. I'd just put vaguely related classes in the same file. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 96, accepted):

While the one class per file policy is strictly enforced in Java, it's not required by C#. However, it's generally a good idea.

I typically break this rule if I have a very small helper class that is only used by the main class, but I prefer to do that as a nested inner class for clarity's sake.

You can however, split a single class into multiple files [using the `partial` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods). This is useful for separating your code from wizard-generated code.

Comment: Maybe it is because Java does not force a single class per file. That is completely false.

Comment: Each class file contains the definition of a single class or interface.
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html
Anonymous inner classes do not count.

Comment: Each file contains the definition of at most one PUBLIC top-level type. You can define as many top-level types as you like in a file, as long as they have package-private access. A rule of thumb is that if the helper is used ONLY by the public class, it can go in the same file.

Comment: Good idea the partial keyword for expand classes definitions with code generated from [T4 Text Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Pretty sure the rule in Java is only one _public_ class per file.

Answer (score 42):

Files are cheap, you aren't doing anyone a favor by consolidating many classes into single files.

In Visual Studio, renaming the file in Solution Explorer will rename the class and all references to that class in your project. Even if you rarely use that feature, the cheapness of files and the ease of managing them mean the benefit is infinitely valuable, when divided by its cost.

Answer (score 18):

As others have said, one file per type in general - although where others have made the public/private distinction, I'd just say "one top-level file per type" (so even top-level internal types get their own files).

I have one exception to this, which is less relevant with the advent of the Func and Action delegate types in .NET 3.5: if I'm defining several delegate types in a project, I often bunch them together in a file called Delegates.cs.

There are other very occasional exceptions too - I recently used partial classes to make several autogenerated classes implement the same interface. They already defined the appropriate methods, so it was just a case of writing:

```
public partial class MessageDescriptor : IDescriptor<MessageDescriptorProto> {}
public partial class FileDescriptor : IDescriptor<FileDescriptorProto> {}
```

etc. Putting all of those into their own files would have been slightly silly.

One thing to bear in mind with all of this: using ReSharper makes it easier to get to your classes whether they're in sensibly named files or not. That's not to say that organising them properly isn't a good thing anyway; it's more to reinforce the notion that ReSharper rocks :)

Answer (score 8):

I personally believe that every class should be in its own file, this includes nested types as well. About the only exceptions to this rule for me are custom delegates.

Most answers have excluded private classes from this rule but I think those should be in their own file as well. Here is a pattern that I currently use for nested types:

Foo.cs: // Contains only Foo implementation

```
public partial class Foo 
{
   // Foo implementation
}
```

Foo.Bar.cs: // Contains only Foo.Bar implementation

```
public partial class Foo
{
  private class Bar
  {
    // Bar implementation
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out a clean transparent way of putting even nested types in their own files. (Not that I necessarily now feel compelled to do so...)

Answer (score 7):

It depends.  Most of the time I would say yes, put them in separate files.  But if I had a private helper class that would only be used by one other class (like a Linked List's Node or Element) I wouldn't recommend separating them.

Answer (score 6):

As someone who has been coding in large files for years (limited to 1,000 lines), in fact, since I started programming as a child, I was surprised at the huge consensus in this "one class per source file" rule.

The "one class per source file" is not without its problems. If you are working on a lot of things at once, you will have many files open. Sure, you could close files once you're finished with them, but what if you needed to re-open them? There is usually a delay every time I open a file.

I am now going to address points others have made and explain what I think are bad reasons for the "one class per source file" rule. A lot of the problems with multiple classes in one source file are resolved with modern source-editing technology.

1. "I hate having to scroll up and down" - Bad Reason - Modern IDEs now either have built-in functionality for getting quickly to the code you want or you can install extensions/plugins for that task. Visual Studio's Solution Explorer does this with its search function, but if that's not enough, buy VisualAssist. VisualAssist provides an outline of the items in your source file. No need to scroll, but double-click on what you want.

There is also code-folding. Too much code? Just collapse it into one line! Problem solved.

2. "Things are easier to find because they're identified by file" - Bad Reason - Again, modern IDEs make it easy to find what you're looking for. Just use Solution Explorer or buy VisualAssist!! The technology is out there, use it!!
3. "Easier to read/too much code" - Bad Reason - I am not blind. I can see. Again, with code-folding I can easily eliminate the clutter and collapse the code I don't need to see. This is not the Stone Age of programming.
4. "You will forget where the classes are in large projects" - Bad Reason - Easy solution: Solution Explorer in Visual Studio and the VisualAssist extension.
5. "You know what's in a project without opening anything" - Good Reason - no dispute with that one.
6. Source Control/Merging - Good Reason - This is actually one good argument in favour of the "one class per source file" rule, especially in team projects. If multiple people are working on the same project. It allows people to see what has changed, at a glance. I can also see how it can complicate merging processes if you use large, multiple-class files.

Source control and merging processes are really the only compelling reason IMO that the "one class per source file" rule should apply. If I'm working on my own individual projects, no, it's not so important.

Answer (score 5):

They should be in different files, even when it seems like overkill. It's a mistake I still frequently make.

There always comes a time when you you've added enough code to a class that it deserves it's own file. If you decide to create a new file for it at that point then you lose your commit history, which always bites you when you lest want it too.

Comment: Totally agree. But Resharper by default add new types into the same file. I sometimes forget to split and hate myself and resharper. I wish to have a pre-commit check

Answer (score 3):

Public classes: yes
Private classes: (needless to say) no

Answer (score 3):

I actually prefer pretty big .cs files, 5000 lines is pretty reasonable IMO, although most of my files at the moment are only about 500-1000 (In C++, however, I've had some scary files), however, . The Object Browser/Class View, Go to Definition, and incremental search (-I; Thanks for that tip, Jeff Atwood!), all make finding any specific class or method pretty easy.

This is probably all because I am terrible about closing unneded tabs.

This is of course highly dependant on how you work, but there are more than enough tools to not need to use horrible old '70s based *file* source navigation (Joking, if it wasn't obvious).

Comment: Personally from a work point of view I find it more awkward to use a massive file than series of separate ones.  Assuming they are sensibly named though,  that's a bug bare of mine!  A file name should reflect the class name IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Of course! Why wouldn't you? Other than private classes it is silly to have multiple classes in a single file.

Answer (score 0):

I think the one-class-per-file approach makes sense. Certainly for different classes, but especially for base and derived classes, whose interactions and dependencies are often non-obvious and error-prone. Separate files makes it straightforward to view/edit base and derived classes side-by-side and scroll independently.

In the days of printed source code listings running to many hundreds of pages (think of a phone book), the "three finger rule" was good a working limit on complexity: if you needed more than three fingers (or paper clips or post-its) as placeholders to understand a module, that module's dependency set was probably too complex. Given that almost no one uses printed source code listings anymore, I'll suggest that this should be updated as the "three window rule" - if you have to open more than three additional windows to understand code displayed in another window, this code probably should be refactored.

A class hierarchy of more than four levels is a code smell, which is in evidence if you need more than four open windows to see the totality of its behavior. Keeping each class in its own file will improve understandability for depth less than four and will give an indirect warning otherwise.