# The classes of a Model should be in one file or in several files? Or when to use them?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

Defining a model in ASP.NET MVC you can have the classes in one *.cs file or in multiple files. 
In one like this:

```
namespace App.Models
{

    public class User
    {
        public string Name{get;set;}
    }

    public class Message
    {
        public string Content{get;set;}
    }

}
```

Or in multiple *.cs saved on the Models folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter whether they're in one or multiple files. Though, there is a standard of having all of your `type`s in their own `.cs` file.

**ViewModels\User.cs:**

```
namespace App.Models
{
    public class User
    {
        public string Name{get;set;}
    }
}
```

**ViewModels\Message.cs:**

```
namespace App.Models
{
    public class Message
    {
        public string Content{get;set;}
    }
}
```

---

**Relevant Post** - [One class per file rule in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434990/one-class-per-file-rule-in-net)