# Enforce only one class per file

Tags: .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, resharper

We want to follow [One class per file rule in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434990/one-class-per-file-rule-in-net)
Is there a way to check this in a continuous integration system? We're using teamcity, but i guess the product doesn't matter.

Can this be checked by resharper, or is it possible to check this with a unit test(Without parsing files myself)?

Comment: That's something that works well in code review. Don't let any code pass with more than one type in it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [nDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) to check that there's more then one class in each file

Answer (score 0):

ReSharper has a refactoring called *Move Types into Matching Files* that you can apply on the whole solution, if you need to, and that would put each type into a separate file, with the exception of inner types, of course.

Let it be said that I disagree **strongly** with the one class per file rule.

Comment: I'm aware that i can move a class into a new file by resharper, but i did not find the option to do this for the whole solution